# Reading a column from CSV file using JAVA

Tags: java, csv

Hi I am trying to read a CSV File called `test.csv` in JAVA .
Below is my code :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class InsertValuesIntoTestDb {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                String splitBy = ",";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.csv"));
        String line = br.readLine();
        while(line!=null){
             String[] b = line.split(splitBy);
             System.out.println(b[0]);
        }
        br.close();

  }
}
```

This is my CSV File (test.csv):

```
a,f,w,b,numinst,af,ub
1RW,800,64,22,1,48:2,true
1RW,800,16,39,1,48:2,true
1RW,800,640,330,1,48:2,true
1RW,800,40,124,1,48:2,true
1RW,800,32,104,1,48:2,true
1RW,800,8,104,1,48:2,true
1R1W,800,65536,39,1,96:96,true
1R1W,800,2048,39,1,96:96,true
1R1W,800,8192,39,1,48:48,true
```

I am trying to print the first column in the csv ,but the output I get is only `a` in an infinite loop . Can anyone please help me fix this code to print the entire first column. Thanks.

Comment: You don't reassign `line` in the loop, so the code loops until line is `null` which will never occour.

Comment: Just a note that hopefully helps you survive some of the pain and suffering that some of us have been through.  Don't write custom parsers and writers for csv...  Sure it seems easy, Each line is a row, each comma is a column.  That is true until its not!  Take a look at http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/ or one of the other library out there.  It will take the pain away from maintaining a proper csv format.

Comment: For the record it is Java, not JAVA.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Read the input continuously within the loop so that the variable `line` is assigned a value other than the initial value

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) !=null) {
  ...
}
```

Aside: This problem has already been solved using CSV libraries such as [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/). Here are examples for [reading and writing](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#how-to-read) CSV files

Comment: What if I want to read a entire row .How can I do that ?

Comment: This will do that. The row is read into the variable `line`...

Answer (score 18):

If you are using [Java 7+](http://radar.oreilly.com/2011/09/java7-features.html), you may want to use [NIO.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html), e.g.:

❍ *Code:*

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    File file = new File("test.csv");

    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(), 
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    for (String line : lines) {
        String[] array = line.split(",", -1);
        System.out.println(array[0]);
    }

}
```

❍ *Output:*

```
a
1RW
1RW
1RW
1RW
1RW
1RW
1R1W
1R1W
1R1W
```

Comment: `List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines()` good one +1

Comment: This doesn't work when the columns contain commas

Comment: @cricket_007 why is it? he is doing split with comma

Comment: @Sha You've clearly never worked with a CSV that contained a list of data within a single column if you don't understand that splitting on just any random comma is not a solution. I understand the question itself is asking for only the first column and the sample data given does not have extra commas itself. However, people are coming here to "parse CSV in Java", and this answer is flawed

Comment: @cricket_007 oh u r talking about comma sperated values in one column? , then i m misunderstood

Comment: @Paul Vargas in the line: List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(),         StandardCharsets.UTF_8); where is the reference to `Files`

Comment: @Gunasekar [`java.nio.file.Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html), since Java 7.

Answer (score 16):

Splitting by comma doesn't work all the time for instance if you have csv file like

```
"Name" , "Job" , "Address"
"Pratiyush, Singh" , "Teacher" , "Berlin, Germany"
```

So, I would recommend using the [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) API:

```
    Reader in = new FileReader("input1.csv");
    Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.parse(in);
    for (CSVRecord record : records) {
      System.out.println(record.get(0));
    }
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

You are not changing the value of line. It should be something like this.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class InsertValuesIntoTestDb {

  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      String splitBy = ",";
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.csv"));
      while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
           String[] b = line.split(splitBy);
           System.out.println(b[0]);
      }
      br.close();

  }
}
```

readLine returns each line and only returns null when there is nothing left. The above code sets line and then checks if it is null.