# Java: easiest way to read from an Excel-style document?

Tags: java, excel

I'm trying to find the best way to read in data from a file similar to an Excel document. It doesn't necessarily need to be an actual excel document, just any file that allows you to enter data in a grid format.
Something where I would be able to do manipulation similar to this:

```
String val = file.readString(column,row);
float val2 = file.readFloat(column,row);
```

I'm sorry, I usually try to do more research before I post a question here but I was having a hard time finding much info. A lot of what I saw was 3rd party libraries that read excel files. I'm really hoping if possible I can avoid downloading libraries and hopefully use built in ones.

So I guess my questions in short are:
What's the most appropriate file format for this?
What's the best way to read data from that file?

Comment: Apache POI will read actual Excel documents.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

Store your data in a CSV and read with any kind of reader (e.g. BufferedReader). This might be the easiest and fastest solution, if you want to use Excel/LibreOffice for entering data.

Please check out the answers in [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-to-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-using-java) [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931929/reading-a-column-from-csv-file-using-java) for [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226830/java-csv-file-easy-read-write) [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169038/read-csv-file-column-by-column).

```
    String csvfile = path;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitby = ";";

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvfile));

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] i = line.split(cvsSplitby);

            // do stuff
        } 


    } catch (all kind of exceptions e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

*Hope I didn't miss anything important.*

**Option 2**

Use [POI Apache](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html).

**Option 3**

I've made some decent experience with [JXL](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/), but I understand that you don'T want to include too many external libs. (I just saw that it hasn't been updated in while. Consider the other options!)

Comment: Interesting, I think I'll try the CSV method. That seems to be pretty close to what I want. Thanks!

Comment: Generally it's best to properly attribute copied code.

Comment: Do you mean Andrew or me? Needless to say [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-to-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-using-java) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931929/reading-a-column-from-csv-file-using-java) [has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226830/java-csv-file-easy-read-write) been [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169038/read-csv-file-column-by-column) before and that I've gotten some pieces from the answers provided there. I just copied it from a project of mine though (fastest way), that's why I didn't attribute properly. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to my mind is CSV. CSV files are just regular text files with the `.csv` filename extension. Data is stored in this format:

```
cell,anothercell,athirdcell
anotherrow,anothercellonthenewrow,thirdcellofsecondrow
```

For more specifics, read the CSV specs [here](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt).