# How to extract data from CSV files in java

Tags: java, eclipse, knn

I am tasked with implementing K nearest neighbor with java. To do so with 2 csv files. One is training and one is test, they contain the data from a census about how much people earn.

An example of some of the file is (this is exactly how it is in the file) :

```
meta data: age, workclass, fnlwgt, education, education-num, marital-status, occupation, relationship, race, sex, capital-gain, capital-loss, hours-per-week, native-country, earns

example 1: 25, Private, 226802, 11th, 7, Never-married, Machine-op-inspct, Own-child, Black, Male, 0, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K

example 2: 38, Private, 89814, HS-grad, 9, Married-civ-spouse, Farming-fishing, Husband, White, Male, 0, 0, 50, United-States, <=50K
```

I just do not understand how to take the key information from these files using scanners and file readers, for example if i wanted just the hours each person worked at the simplist.

If you have a basic outline of how to implement this with knn too would be appericated...

sorry for breaking any rules or not understanding full how to ask questions in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate: see [answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274259/read-csv-with-scanner) and [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931929/reading-a-column-from-csv-file-using-java)

Comment: dont parse CSV yourself, use a library to parse it.  The duplicate mentions Apache Commons CSV.  Another is opencsv.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap a FileReader in a BufferedReader, then read line-by-line and tokenize with a split(",") or a Scanner. Maybe something like this?

```
public void readCsv() throws IOException {
    File file = new File("filename.csv");
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    String line;
    String[] tokenizedLine;

    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        tokenizedLine = parse(line);
        // do stuff with your array
    }
}

private String[] parse(String line) { // use split or Scanner
    return line.split(",");
}
```